# WebApi Controller: Accessing database more than once, using Controller's own method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a, let's say, NodeController for a project of mine. It is linked up to a database, and all of its methods take an ID for which Node to access in the EF database.
A node can have a *dependency* on another Node, meaning that, if I want to, say, "execute" one Node, I must check whether any dependency-node has already been executed or not, and fail, if not all dependencies have been executed.

I will present partial versions of two of my methods, whereas one uses the other, but first, there is our Controller's constructor, as will be mentioned later on:

```
private readonly NodeDBContext _context;

public NodeController()
{
    _context = new NodeDBContext();
}
```

Is this a correct way to use a DbContext, or should we limit ourselves to using "using" statements whenever we perform something actually database-related (Getting or Putting, in our case)?

```
[ResponseType(typeof(bool))]
[HttpGet]
[Route("node/{id}/executed")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Executed(int id)
{
    var node = await NodeControllerHelper.GetNode(_context, id);
    if (node == null) return BadRequest("There is no such Node");
    return Ok(node.Executed);
}
```

As you can see, the method above uses a "_context", which is a NodeDbContext, inheriting from DbContext. Is it correct for me to pass this field-ified DbContext to the method that will retrieve the Node object from the database?
Below is the method which will take use of both the "NodeControllerHelper.GetNode" method *as well as* the Executed(int id) method:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("node/{id}/executed")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Executed(int id, PutMessage message)
{
    //Interpret input
    var node = await NodeControllerHelper.GetNode(_context, id);
    if (node == null) return BadRequest("There is no such Node");

    foreach (var condition in node.Conditions)
    {
        bool executed = false;
        response = await Executed(condition.Id).Result.ExecuteAsync(new CancellationToken(false));
        executed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    if (!executed)
    { // Precondition has not been executed
        await NodeControllerHelper.UnlockNodeIfSelfLockedAndSave(_context, node);
        return BadRequest("One or more preconditions are not currently fulfilled.");
    }
}
```

As can be seen, first the .GetNode call is made, meaning there is one call to the DbContext in there, and also, there is the "Executed(condition.Id)" call, which of course ends up calling the .GetNode method once more.
This is where we seem to have hit some sort of rock, as the PUT /executed method appears to fail on more than half of occasions, however sometimes manages to squeeze by, beyond my understanding.

I have a more general question in regards how we can best ensure happiness on all ranks of our Controller code;

- What is the best practice for managing our DbContext? Currently, it is being instantiated in the constructor of the controller, set to a private readonly field and is dispersed down into "deeper" method calls. This seems to make some troubles. When debugging, once we reach the second call of the .GetNode method, and we make the step to go past the call 'get'ting from the database's table, debugging mysteriously stops, some Exception is thrown, and the client we use to call to the Api doesn't receive any HttpResponseMessage. An alternative is to have "using" statements which create their own short-lived DbContext, however we tried this implementation earlier and it seemed to have the same issue at the second .GetNode call.

Below is the GetNode method, for reference:

```
public static async Task<Node> GetNode(NodeDBContext context, int id)
{
    var node = await context.Nodes.FindAsync(id);
    return node;
}
```

Well damn, this post ended up being longer, than I had initially wanted to present, although code-cutting has occured as well. I hope that somebody out there sees something that is wrongly done by us, and can correct us in our perhaps slightly fundamental mistake of implementation...

Thank you a lot in advance,
Kirluu

Comment: Darn, I messed up the code for the PUT /executed method. The "if" is supposed to be inside the foreach, and in practice, some more code of course follows the foreach (the case where all preconditions are fulfilled).

Comment: I realize that my post is pretty horrible, and I'm sorry for that. A main question I'm holding in my hands, yet, is whether it's allowed/recommended at all, to call an ApiController's method from another one of its own methods?

Comment: Why would you do that? It's difficult to get a clear picture how your calls are routed. But you shouldn't be calling an APi method from within the same controller. That is why you should create classes that have the single responsibility of doing what you want and also, consider using dependency injection to inject the DbContext